# android opengl GLES20: how to draw many triangles with each model matrix? (with good performance))

Tags: android, matrix, opengl-es

I want to make a audio visualizer with android GLES20.
[captured image that I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayrpx.png)

each rectangle's position is (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)

each rectangle has different model matrix. (rotate, translate, scale)

And each rectangle draw with GLES20.glDrawArrays.
But this way cost too much time. (using that method 200 times)
(Of course, I want 60 FPS.)

If I use GLES20.glDrawArrays method one time and draw all rectangles(=triangles) at once, performance will become good.

How can I draw triangles with one time using GLES20.glDrawArrays method?
(triangle has same position buffer, different model matrix)

```
private void draw(int[] bufferId, int color, float[] modelMatrix, int count) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);
    int uMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    int aPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
    int aColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Color");


    Matrix.multiplyMM(MVMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, MVMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, MVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttrib4f(aColorHandle, Color.red(color) / 255f, Color.green(color) / 255f, Color.blue(color) / 255f, Color.alpha(color) / 255f);

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId[0]);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, count);
}
```

this method draw one rectangle with buffer, color, model matrix. (count = 4)

Comment: Firstly, I would get rid of the glUseProgram line at the beginning of this draw method. It's unnecessary if every rectangle is using the same program (which it looks like it they are), and I'm no expert but that may be slowing down your FPS (though not by much). Instead, in your onDrawFrame() method, before you call draw on every rectangle, insert the glUseProgram line.

Comment: In addition, these handles,

    int uMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    int aPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
    int aColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Color");

are the same for each rectangle. This probably won't improve FPS by that much, but I wouldn't waste any time defining these handles for EVERY rectangle. Instead, put these lines in the onSurfaceCreated() method, and allow access to them in the draw() method of the rectangles.

Comment: These were just suggestions on slightly improving the FPS, they won't show any substantial improvement in FPS, but it might help a little. I have no idea what your current FPS is

Answer (score 0):

Batch the vertices in a single draw call, upload an array uniform matrices, and add a vertex attribute to each rectangle telling them which array index to use.

That said - there are likely to be limits on how much uniform space you can use, so 200 matrices is unlikely to work. Given you're just processing rectangles which has a small number of vertices, it's probably actually faster just to animate them on the CPU and upload the pre-transformed clip-space coordinates to the GPU.